# Capturing text from HTML response and writing condition in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node js and never worked earlier on it. I need your help to resolve the issue.
I have the following code

```
async function reserved_slot(page, target_url) {
        var fifthwkslotdate= new Date();
        fifthwkslotdate.setDate(fifthwkslotdate.getDate() + 7);
        await page.goto(`${target_url}en-GB/slots/delivery/${fifthwkslotdate}?slotGroup=1`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
        await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
        await page.screenshot({path: 'HomeDeliveryFifthwkPage.png'});
        await page.click('[class="button button-secondary small available-slot--button available-slot--button--cc-link-enabled"]');
        await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'Reservedelslotpage.png'});
}
```

By using this code I am reserving the slot. But if the slot is not available on the page I have to go to another page to book the slot.

1. `${target_url}en-GB/slots/delivery/${fifthwkslotdate}?slotGroup=1`  after going to this page I can come to know whether the slot is there or not by seeing this message "Delivery slots for these dates are fully booked". How to capture this value from the above HTML page response.
2. If slot is available i can book the slot using `"await page.click('[class="button button-secondary small available-slot--button available-slot--button--cc-link-enabled"]');"` other wise i have to go other page by using`"fifthwkslotdate.setDate(fifthwkslotdate.getDate() + 0);"` how to implement this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Using the length of the available button in the page I was able to reserve slots in multiple weeks

```
const classlength =   await page.evaluate(() => {
     return  document.getElementsByClassName("button button-secondary small available-slot--button available-slot--button--cc-link-enabled").length;
   });  

console.log('classnamevalue', classlength );

    if (classlength > 0) {
        await page.click('[class="button button-secondary small available-slot--button available-slot--button--cc-link-enabled"]');
        await page.waitForTimeout(3000);           
        await page.screenshot({
            path: 'Reservedelslot3rdwkpage.png'
        });
    } else {
    var secondwkslotdate = new Date();
        secondwkslotdate.setDate(secondwkslotdate.getDate() + 7);
        await page.goto(`${target_url}en-GB/slots/delivery/${secondwkslotdate}?slotGroup=1`, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
        });
        await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
        await page.screenshot({
            path: 'HomeDelivery2ndwkPage.png'
        });
        await page.click('[class="button button-secondary small available-slot--button available-slot--button--cc-link-enabled"]');
        await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
        await page.screenshot({
            path: 'Reservedelslot2rdwkpage.png'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.